# What does this JS object declaration syntax mean?

Tags: javascript

I am working through a node.js beginners tutorial and came across this piece of code:

```
const respondEcho = (req, res) => {
    const { input = '' } = querystring.parse(
        req.url.split('?').slice(1).join('')
    )
}
```

The syntax of this line `const { input = '' } = querystring.parse()` is a little confusing to me.
It seems like a declaration of a constant object set equal to a method which returns key value pairs. What I don't understand however is the assignment inside the curly braces - if this was an object declaration then it would be like this rather:

```
const {input: ''}
```

The `input=''` seems like it would be a default value on the object. Could someone explain the meaning of this syntax?

Comment: [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: It's destructuring along with a default value if the property doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { foo = '' } = bar
```

means that you are destructuring the `foo` property from `bar` and you are assigning a default value to it incase it is `falsy`.

It is practically the same as doing:

```
let foo = bar.foo;

if (foo === undefined) {
  foo = '';
}
```

Comment: So in this case 'input' is actually a property name on the object that querystring.parse returns?

Comment: Default values are only used if the argument is missing or undefined, not for all falsey values.

Comment: @Blargian Yes, that's how destructuring works.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, new to JS so just wanted to confirm. Array destructuring works positionally whereas object destructuring is by name. Hadn't seen the default value assignment with object destructuring before.

Comment: So `if (!foo)` should be `if (foo === undefined)`

Comment: @Barmar you are right, thank you. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with a default value in the case that the value unpacked from the object is undefined.